# How to call the API and receive its information before rendering the routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

I have a React app with some public/private routes defined and I need to pass the user information into the private route. I'm trying to call the API (that returns the user details) and receive it before rendering the routes but can't make it work - the routes are being rendered before getting the response so the user is getting empty value. I've tried to use async/await without success in this case. Or maybe if anyone know a better approach for this. Thanks!

```
export const Routes = () => {

    const user = axios.get('/login').then(function(res) { return res })

    return (
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} user={user} />
            <Route component={Error404} />
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using state to create the routes after you know the response from your axios request? 
Something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, PrivateRoute } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import Home from "./Home";
import Error404 from "./Error404";

const Routes = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/login").then(res => {
      setUser(res);
    });
  }, []);

  return user ? (
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} user={user} />
      <Route component={Error404} />
    </Switch>
  ) : null;
};

export default Routes;
```

You can improve it, depending on your responses and other components.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In your code what happens if there is no information for the user? Eg: the user is not logged in, so the API will return false. I need that in this case the routes still being rendered but will redirect the user to /login

Comment: You can use other state (like [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState()) and render Home component only if isLogged is true. Similar to the conditional I've user with user, but with isLogged

Comment: I've made some little adaptations and now it's working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like this:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  useLoaderData,
} from "react-router-dom";

function loader() {
  return fetchFakeAlbums();
}

export function Albums() {
  const albums = useLoaderData();
  // ...
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    loader: loader,
    element: <Albums />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(el).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

`react-router-dom` provide `useLoaderData`, which can be used to prefetch data before route load!

Reference: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data