# How do I fetch data from API before render method called? (react, passport, express)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to verify that the user is authenticated with passport before allowing them to access a certain route. To do so, I need to access my API which will return the authentication status of my user. However, I wish to make the call before the route has rendered so that the route remains protected. Here is my current attempt:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.fetchAuthState().then(result => console.log('result',result))
        this.state = { 
            isAuth: false, 
            error: null
        }
    }
    async fetchAuthState() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/logincheck', {
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                accept: 'application/json',
              },
            });
            return await response.json();
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            this.setState({ error });
          }
      };

    render() {
      console.log('client check', this.state.isAuth)
      const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props
      return (
        <Route 
          {...props} 
          render={props => (
            this.state.isAuth ?
              <Component {...props} /> :
              <Redirect to='/login' />
          )} 
        />
      )
    }
  }

  export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Here is the server side code:

```
app.get('/logincheck', (req, res) =>{
  res.send(req.isAuthenticated())
})
```

I figured that because of the react lifecycle, the fetch should be called in the constructor, and then stored in state. However, when I try to store the result, either directly or in a temporary variable, the fetch result shows undefined. I have checked the passport docs for any client side form of isAuthenticated(), but it appears that it only works server side. I was considering implementing a jwt token system to see if that would be a better way to maintain authentication status but thought that having an api route to check would be easier. I am new to web development so any advice/criticism would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676644/how-to-call-the-api-and-receive-its-information-before-rendering-the-routes, but I would like to keep my component as a class since I am passing my route component as a prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding an extra state variable - something like `loading` - and then toggling it when the API returns a response. But I would refactor your code slightly to make it look like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            isAuth: false, 
            error: null
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/logincheck', {
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                accept: 'application/json',
              },
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
              this.setState({isAuth: json.isAuth, loading: false})
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
      }

    render() {
      console.log('client check', this.state.isAuth)
      const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props;
      const {loading, isAuth} = this.state;
      return (
        <Route 
          {...props} 
          render={() => {
            return loading ?
                <div>Loading...</div>
                :
                isAuth ?
                   this.props.children
                :
                    <Redirect to='/login' />
        }} />
      )
    }
  }

  export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: This sets isAuth to undefined unfortunately. I tried switching the server response to a json type but this also does not seem to work

Comment: @MichaelHla The code is a template. I have no idea what your JSON response looks like so I assume: `this.setState({isAuth: json.isAuth, loading: false})` hence the `undefined` in `isAuth`

Comment: Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong? This seems like it should work `app.get('/logincheck', (req, res) =>{
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.send({isAuth: true})
  }
  else res.send({isAuth: false})
})`

Comment: @MichaelHla Change `.send(...)` to `.json(...)`

Comment: Can you console out your response in the second "then" in your componetdidmount?

Comment: ƒ json() { [native code] } logged for json, isAuth not updated

Comment: @MichaelHla Makes me think in your code, in the first `then` you have `.then(res => res.json)` instead of `.then(res => res.json())`. Can you check?

Comment: @MichaelHla glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some loading screen until authentication response arrived.

Initiate loading state and do the fetch on component mount

```
class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = { 
            isAuth: false, 
            error: null,
            loading:true // default loading will be true
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      this.fetchAuthState().then(result => this.setState({loading:false})) // after fetch end set loading false
    }
    ....
     render() {
      console.log('client check', this.state.isAuth)
      const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props
      return (
        {this.state.loading ? <LoadingComponent/> :<Route  
          {...props} 
          render={props => (
            this.state.isAuth ?
              <Component {...props} /> :
              <Redirect to='/login' />
          )} 
        />}
      )
    }
}
```